# How to get values using post method

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to print values submitted in the form using post method. But i cant get to display anything. After submitting the form anything is displayed. Not even the sentence in echo. I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my code. thanks in advance.

I have tried using `if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST"){}`, I have tried to put the variable in `isset()`, still did not work.

**register.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php'); // this is database connection file
error_reporting(0);
echo $_POST["name"]; 
?>
```

**config.php**

```
 <?php

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","music_pro");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo"Failed to connect : " . mysqli_connect_error(); 

}

?>
```

**html code**

```
<form method="post" name="register" action="register.php">
    <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" 
     required>
    <label for="uname"><b>User ID</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter your user id" 
     required>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your 
     password" 
    id="pwd" required>
    <label for="confirmPassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Please 
    confirm password" id="cofirmpsw" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Register"></form>
```

Comment: you should enable php errors, my guess, config.php has an error.

Comment: Put `var_dump($_POST);` at the very beginning of your script, after session_start. If that only shows an empty array, then you didn’t have any POST data to begin with.

Comment: Post your HTML Code also.

Comment: Please Try this $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","music_pro"); in your config file

Comment: please check ,your button click goes to register.php in browser address bar

Comment: We can't help you further unless you provide a way for us to reproduce your issue at our end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing something, check if `$_POST` empty or not,

register.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
include 'config.php'; // this is database connection file
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);die;
}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "music_pro");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect : " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
```

yourxyz.html or yourxyz.php

```
<form method="post" name="register" action="register.php">
    <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email id" required>
    <label for="uname"><b>User ID</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Enter your user id" required>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your 
     password" id="pwd" required>
    <label for="confirmPassword"><b>Confirm Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Please 
    confirm password" id="cofirmpsw" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

This should work. And once check whether input element is having a name attribute with name as its name.

Comment: Check my updated answer, it should work or atleast throw error. Please update your question with the error if its there.

Comment: No Offence, I gave OP an ocean to get what OP want.

Answer (score 0):

if your form and php code are in one page then change first line of form as below:

```
<form method="post" name="register" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME''];?>">
```

Comment: thank you... My post array was empty. hence it did not show anything. Got the solution. :)

Comment: just let me know that your HTML is in register.php or in seperate file? if so, do this two file, that is, your HTML file and register.php are in same directory??